# prepend date to a filename in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following shell script and want to change the filename `db_backup.sql` to be change so the current date is prepended to it e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd-db_backup.sql`

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump ... /_sql/db_backup.sql
gzip -f _sql/db_backup.sql
```

Simple question, hopefully quick and simple answer!

Comment: Your title mentions perl, you script is shell...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `date` command to do what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh
fspec=/_sql/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-db_backup.sql
mysqldump ... ${fspec}
gzip -f ${fspec}
```

If you're using a shell that doesn't support `$()`, you may need to use backticks instead:

```
fspec=/_sql/`date +%Y-%m-%d`-db_backup.sql
```

Comment: I though he said perl script :(

Answer (score 0):

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $file = sprintf("%s-db_backup.sql",  strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime);
```